# convert the bytes in to readable string format in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, httpresponse

I am working on an BB app in which I need to maintain a HTTP connection and with a name of image which is stored on server to get the text written in that image document.

I am getting the response in RTF format.
When I directly hit the server on open browser Chrome, I RTF file get downloaded. 
Now I needs to perform that programetically,

```
1) Either convert the bytes which are coming in response in a simple string format so that I can read that.
```

or

```
2) Download the file as its happening on the browser manually so that by reading that file I read the information written in the document.
```

please suggest me how can I read the data from server by hitting any URL?

Currently I am working with this code:

```
try {
    byte []b = send("new_image.JPG");
    String s = new String(b, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(s);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

public byte[] send(String Imagename) throws Exception
    {
        HttpConnection hc = null;
        String imageName = "BasicExp_1345619462234.jpg";
            InputStream is = null;
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] res = null;

        try
        {
        hc = (HttpConnection) Connector.open("http://webservice.tvdevphp.com/basisexpdemo/webservices/ocr.php?imgname="+imageName);
            hc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;");
        hc.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
            int ch;
        StringBuffer sb= new StringBuffer();
        is = hc.openInputStream();
            while ((ch = is.read()) != -1)
            {
            bos.write(ch);
            sb.append(ch);
            }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        res = bos.toByteArray();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                if(bos != null)
                    bos.close();

                if(is != null)
                    is.close();

                if(hc != null)
                    hc.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e2)
            {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

The response is like:

**{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\uc1\deflang1033\adeflang1033...................**

I can read the data but its not formatted, so that i can read that programetically too.

Answer (score 0):

I have done with this task....
Actually the mistake was on server side.
When they were performing OCR, the format parameter was not corrected that was reason.

Comment: if you answer your own question, please also **accept** it, so we know you don't still need help.  thanks!